knife vault show a single value nested in an array
We have data stored in a Chef vault in the below manner:

Vault - secrets

Item - test

Value - teamcity_agent
Nested under that is agent_key


teamcity_agent:
  username:     helloworld
  agent_key:    123ABC456DEF

The command we've been running is:
knife vault show secrets vault-bwi-mainline teamcity_agent - but it returns all of teamcity_agent
We'd like to use a single knife command to return only agent_key.  We know we can do a -Fjson and pipe it into jq and then take advantage JSON to read values with .  What we're trying to find out is how to do it with a single knife command and not piping things together with jq or grep
Official Chef documentation shows:
knife vault show VAULT [ITEM] [VALUES] (options)
We tried the below examples to try and they either return nothing or the full teamcity_agent stanza:
knife vault show secrets test "teamcity_agent.agent_key"
knife vault show secrets test [teamcity_agent,agent_key]
knife vault show secrets test teamcity_agent agent_key


Sub-values of an item are supported, but not sub-sub-values.
The documentation gives the example:
knife vault show passwords root "username, password"

where passwords is a vault and root is an item.
teamcity_agent is already a sub-value of the vault-bwi-mainline item.
I suspect that vault-bwi-mainline is a complex object, possibly large enough to be its own vault.
Your options are:

Keep the current structure and use jq.

Make vault-bwi-mainline its own vault.  Then, teamcity_agent will be an item and you can do:
knife vault show vault-bwi-mainline teamcity_agent "agent_key"



Thank you for this answer and confirming what we may have been thinking.  I do like your 2nd idea and move the name of our vault up as well.  Really appreciate it!  :)
